# EmberJS / Ember-data: hasMany collection incomplete, despite all IDs exist

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, has-many

*installed versions*

```
ember-cli   2.14.2
ember-data  2.14.10
```

**A little perspective:**

I have a service called `menu` that performs store queries inside computed properties. One of these store queries is behaving rather weird. It fetches all records under the model name `product-segment` from a fully functional JSON API. This model has a n-n relationship to a model called `product`, referenced through `hasMany` DS objects:

*models/product-segment.js*

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

    products: DS.hasMany('product'),
    // ...
});
```

*models/product.js*

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

    productSegments: DS.hasMany('product-segment'),
    // ...
})
```

**The problem:**

Now, when I fetch these `product-segment` models, I instruct the API to `{ include: 'products' }`, and the API does as is requested. The response includes 15 related `product` models for a particular `product-segment`, which is correct.

*(let's call this particular `product-segment` **segment x**, it's the subject for all my debugging info below)*

However, accessing the relationship collection on **segment x** from any context, at any time, only returns me 12 models, so 3 are missing. I witnessed similar issues with other `product-segment` models, so I don't think it's an issue with one specific model.

**More perspective**

I initially thought I was dealing with a race condition of some kind, and to be sure I created a computed property - `test` - to find out, and I dumped `{{menu.test}}` into my view to tickle the computed prop.

Here's the bare minimum info inside `services/menu.js`

```js
export default Service.extend({

    store: inject(),

    activeProductSegment: null,

    // As a note: this does not trigger an infinite loop
    productSegments: computed('store.product.[]', 'store.product-segment.[]', function() {
        return get(this, 'store').findAll('product-segment', { include: 'products' });
    }),

    test: computed('activeProductSegment', function() {
        let segment = get(this, 'activeProductSegment');

        if (segment) {
            console.log(segment.hasMany('products').ids());
            console.log(get(segment, 'products').mapBy('id'));
        }
    }),
});
```

The property `activeProductSegment` is being set to different `product-segment` model instances through an action of a component , which looks like this:

```
export default Component.extend({
    menu: inject(), // menu service is injected here...

    actions: {
        setProductSegment(segment) {
            get(this, 'menu').set('activeProductSegment', segment);
        }
    }
});
```

The action itself works as expected, and is actually quite unrelated to my problem. `activeProductSegment` is never updated in any other way. The view passes this action `product-segment` model objects:

```
{{#each menu.productSegments as |segment|}}
    <li {{action 'setProductSegment' segment}}>{{segment.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

**Trouble starts here**

I set `menu.activeProductSegment` to **segment x** by clicking its associated `<li>` element.

When I now try to get all related `product` models of **segment x**, only 12 of 15 models are present within the returned collection. To be sure that the JSON response was really fine (i.e. the type definitions etc. are right) I checked the amount of `product` IDs that were registered at **segment x**. I logged the following line (the context of the logs below is in the `Ember.Service` snippet above):

```
console.log(segment.hasMany('products').ids());
```

That returned me an array with 15 correct IDs, so **segment x** has all id's as it is supposed to have. All `product` models of those id's have been included in the response, so I suppose there should be no issue with async data of some kind. Still, the following line gave me back an array of 12 id's:

```
console.log(get(segment, 'products').mapBy('id'));
```

I tried putting the 2 logs into a 2-second `setTimeout`, but the result stayed identical:

[image: This is the 2 logs]

I'm starting to think this is a bug, since I noticed that the first time that an id was not accompanied by a model, is when for the first time the next ID is lower than the preceding ID.

**Update on the above** I tried a different order in the response, and note the second and the third id's: `"7", "6"`. Guess this is not the problem:

[image]

Unless I misunderstand, the models should be *live*, so any relationship is supposed to update as data becomes available. I think it is very unlikely this has anything to do with malformed data.

What could be the cause for the missing models in the `hasMany` relationship collection, despite the fact that all necessary ids are properly registered at the `hasMany` relationship object, and we're not required to await arrival of any async/network data at this point? And what might be a suitable solution to the problem?

Comment: The CP `productSegments` gets recomputed just once? This might be tricky since it depends on `'store.product.[]', 'store.product-segment.[]'` which actually change as the CP's function (`this.store.findAll()`) pushes records into the store, doesn't it? This is pure guess but worth further examination

Comment: I also remember I had similar problem but it rooted in using nested records in another record. Something Ember-data recommends not to do. Since my `content` model might but not necessarily had to load related models `localized-content`, I ended up checking its state as follows:
```// app/models/content.js
   isFullyLoaded: computed('localizedContent', function () {
      return Ember.isPresent(this.hasMany('localizedContent').value());
    }),```

Comment: @Pavol I had that exact concern too, but this does not trigger an infinite loop. If the store gets a query command identical to one previously given, it will, instead of again contact the API, just give back cached content, unless explicitly told otherwise.

Comment: Ok, one attempt more. What do you see when running this:
`get(segment, 'products').then(()=>console.log(get(segment, 'products').mapBy('id')));`
Could it be that you truly run in a race condition and explicitly requesting relationship resolution solves the problem?

Comment: Ok I tried, exact same thing. It's also funny that its alway 12 id's, never 13, never 11. I'm just clueless :P

Comment: I remember I had completely same symptoms but can't remember how I solved it. Bugs me no less than it bugs you now :D

Answer (score 0):

I know it does not appear to be related to async issues, but I would still try defining the hasMany as not async:

```js
products: DS.hasMany('product', {async: true}),
```